# Java using AWT list and sockets to send a direct message in a chat room

Tags: java, sockets, components, client-server, awt

I am using Java sockets to create a simple chat room and using AWT component for the GUI. I have all functions of the chat room working, it sends and recieves messages to/from all users, etc... One requirement was to make a list that updates as users enter and leave the chat. I have this function working and my solution was to have my server print the current names of the handlers to a file and then the client grabs the names from the file and adds it to the list. To do this, I made a method that I put in a for(;;) loop so the list continuously updates as users enter/ leave the chat. These requirements all work fine...

MY PROBLEM: The next requirement states: "A user should be able to select a single user from the user list. While a name is selected, all messages sent will be private - only sent to that user." I cannot figure out how to get the selected name back to the server so that someone can send messages only to the username that is selected. Is this even possible with the way I handled creating my list? If so do you have any ideas on how to make this possible? I've been stumped on this for a few days and I am almost thinking at this point that it is not possible and I should rethink my logic for the list. If it is not possible, do you have any ideas for a better solution for my list?

Thank you!

Client file:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ClientFrame extends Frame{

    public ClientFrame(){
        setSize(500,500);
        setTitle("Chat Client");

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent We){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        add(new ClientPanel(new FrameContainer(this)), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ClientFrame();
    }

} // end ClientFrame

class ClientPanel extends Panel implements ActionListener, Runnable, ItemListener{
    TextField tf;
    TextArea ta;
    List list;
    Button connect, disconnect;
    Socket socketToServer;
    PrintWriter pw;
    BufferedReader br;
    Thread t;
    String userName;
    FrameContainer fc;

    public ClientPanel(FrameContainer fc){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        tf = new TextField();
        ta = new TextArea();
        list = new List();
        this.fc = fc;
        connect = new Button("Connect");
        disconnect = new Button("Disconnect");
        Panel bPanel = new Panel();
        bPanel.add(connect);
        disconnect.setEnabled(false);
        bPanel.add(disconnect);
        
        tf.addActionListener(this);
        connect.addActionListener(this);
        disconnect.addActionListener(this);
        list.addItemListener(this);

        add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(list, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(bPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);        
        
    } // end ClientPanel constructor

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if (ae.getSource() == tf){
            String temp = tf.getText();
            pw.println(userName+": "+temp);
            tf.setText("");
        } else if (ae.getSource() == connect){
            if(tf.getText() == null || tf.getText().equals("")){
                    ta.append("Must enter a name to connect\n");
                }else { 
                    setUsername(tf.getText());
                    fc.getFrame().setTitle(userName);
                    connect.setEnabled(false);
                    disconnect.setEnabled(true);
                    tf.setText("");     
                    try{
                        socketToServer = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3000);
                        pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter
                                (socketToServer.getOutputStream()), true);
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                                (socketToServer.getInputStream()));
                    }catch(UnknownHostException uhe){
                        System.out.println(uhe.getMessage());
                    }catch(IOException ioe){
                        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
                    } 
                }
                    t = new Thread(this);
                    t.start();
                    pw.println(userName);
                    pw.println(userName +" has entered the chat.");
                    
        }else if (ae.getSource() == disconnect){
            try{
                pw.println(userName +" has left the chat.");
                list.removeAll();
                fc.getFrame().setTitle("Chat Client");
                t.interrupt();
                br.close();
                pw.close();
                socketToServer.close();
                connect.setEnabled(true);
                disconnect.setEnabled(false);
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            }
        }
    } // end actionPerformed

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
            if(ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                String user = list.getSelectedItem();


            }else if(ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
                break;
            }

    } // end itemStateChanged

    public void run(){
            try {
                for (;;) {

                    if(socketToServer.isClosed() == true) {
                        break;
                    }
                    setList();
                    try {
                        String temp = br.readLine();
                        ta.append(temp + "\n");

                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());

                    }
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Disconnected.");
            }
    } // end run

    public void setList(){
        list.removeAll();
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader("onlinelist.txt"));
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                this.list.add(line);            
            }
                br.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
            System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }

    } // end setList

    public void setUsername(String userName){
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return userName;
    }

    

} // end ClientPanel


// Container class to change title of frame

class FrameContainer{
    ClientFrame f;

    public FrameContainer(ClientFrame f){
        setFrame(f);    
    }

    public ClientFrame getFrame(){
        return f;
    }
    public void setFrame(ClientFrame f){
        this.f = f;
    }
}
```

Server file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.*;

public class ThreadedServerWithPresence{  
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        ArrayList<ThreadedHandlerWithPresence> handlers;
            try{    
            handlers = new ArrayList<ThreadedHandlerWithPresence>();
            ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(3000);
                for(;;){  
                Socket incoming = s.accept();
                new ThreadedHandlerWithPresence(incoming, 
                                    handlers).start();
                }   
            }catch (Exception e){  
                System.out.println(e);
            }
    } 
}

class ThreadedHandlerWithPresence extends Thread{  

    Socket incoming;
    ArrayList<ThreadedHandlerWithPresence> handlers;
    PrintWriter pw;
    BufferedReader br;
    String userName;
    ArrayList<String> list;

    public ThreadedHandlerWithPresence(Socket i,
        ArrayList<ThreadedHandlerWithPresence> handlers){ 
        incoming = i;
        this.handlers = handlers;
        handlers.add(this);
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName){
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserName(){
        return userName;
    }


   
    public void run(){  
        try{    
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                            (incoming.getInputStream()));

            pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter
                            (incoming.getOutputStream()),true);
           
            setUserName(br.readLine());
            createList();

            for(;;){

                String temp = br.readLine();
                if(temp == null)
                break;              

                System.out.println("Message read: " + temp);
                
                    for(int i = 0; i < handlers.size(); i++){
                        handlers.get(i).pw.println(temp);
                    }
                
            }           
            }catch (Exception e){  
                System.out.println(e);
            }finally{
                handlers.remove(this);
                createList(); 
            } 
    }

    public void createList(){
            try{
                PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(
                    new FileWriter("onlinelist.txt"));
                for(int i = 0; i < handlers.size(); i++){
                    p.println(handlers.get(i).getUserName());                   
                }
                p.close();
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you include the "Swing" tag when you are using AWT components? Swing components start with "J".

Comment: *To do this, I made a method that I put in a for(;;) loop so the list continuously updates* - doesn't sound very efficient. I would suggest you need to add a "message type" to each message. So you might have message types like: "userAdded", "userRemoed", "chat", "privateChat". Then each message type would have different data associated with the message. For userAddedRemoved you would just pass the user name. For the  "chat" you would just pass the message. For the "privateChate" you would pass the user and message. The server and/or client would then need to parse each message.